# How do you abstract interface classes

Tags: c++

I'm trying to work with my own little framework(only for interest actually:) ) recently. I'd like to abstract an interface to describe a process with an input and an output. So I defined a class `BaseInput` and a class `Baseoutput`. And here is the interface.

```
class IProcess
{
public:
    virtual void Proc(BaseInput &input) = 0;
};
```

And here is my problem. The classes derived from `IProcess` have to make `BaseInput` as its argument's type according to the standard of C++. I expect the subclasses could be like this(I know it's wrong):

```
class ProcessA : public IProcess
{
public:
    void Proc(MyInput &input) override;
};
```

I know this couldn't compile correctly. And I also know It could convert to a `MyInput` pointer in `ProcessA::Proc`. I considered Dependency Injection but I don't know whether it could solve my problem.

How do you guys solve such kinds of problems in the real project?

P.S. **I actually found a similar situation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12369206/using-subclass-type-parameters-in-virtual-functions)**

**Edit 1**:
Well, I'm extremely sorry for my wrong expression. And thanks for all you guys' helping. `MyInput` actually brings some data like this:

```
class MyInput : public BaseInput
{
public:
    //... some functions
    std::vector<int> m_Data;
};
```

AKA the argument's type should be `MyInput&` if I need to access `m_Data` from `proc` without any pointer converting. What I want to achieve is architecture just like `.NET Core MVC`. An input worker class accept different input(from files, internet or serial ports...), pack them into classes derived from `BaseInput` and give it to some process classes derived from `IProcess` (maybe there also could be some middleware) and finally return a result packaged by output classes derived from `BaseOutput`.

It might be a really dumb architecture. I'm also wondering how to make it better. I had also considered not to pack those input. But I don't know how :-x

Thanks to all you guys again.

Comment: What do you want to gain from creating a base class?

Comment: It is turtles all the way down in interface-based design, you discovered that BaseInput should probably be an interface as well.  Or, sure, you'll assume that the concrete Process implementation already knows about input.

Comment: Probably something goes wrong with your architecture if you create an abstract class to the process **any** input and don't really do this in the child class

Comment: I haven't done c++ for a long time. But I remember that interface classes had a protected ctor and that these interfaces were inherited with public virtual IClassname. So when it's still needed today, it maybe would help you to make your design more clean.

Comment: @user743414 An abstract or interface class is a class that contains at least one **pure virtual** method (`virtual ... = 0;`) no matter if the constructor is `public` or `protected` ;)

Comment: @Fareanor Ah okay. Thank's. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, `MyInput` must inherits `BaseInput`. Then, `ProcessA::Proc` must have the same protoype than the `IProcess::proc` that it is supposed to override (So it must take a `BaseInput` as parameter too).

By using **polymorphism**, you will be able to pass a `MyInput` when calling the function since you passed a reference and that `MyInput` inherits `BaseInput`.

---

Here is an example:

*.h*:

```
class BaseInput
{
    public:
        virtual ~BaseInput();
        virtual void display();
};
class MyInput : public BaseInput
{
    public:
        void display() override;
};

class IProcess
{
    public:
        virtual ~IProcess();
        virtual void proc(BaseInput & input) = 0;
};
class ProcessA : public IProcess
{
    public:
        void proc(BaseInput & input) override;
};
```

*.cpp*:

```
BaseInput::~BaseInput()
{}
void BaseInput::display()
{
    std::cout << "BaseInput::display()" << std::endl;
}
void MyInput::display()
{
    std::cout << "MyInput::display()" << std::endl;
}

IProcess::~IProcess()
{}

void ProcessA::proc(BaseInput & input)
{
    input.display();
}
```

*main*:

```
int main()
{
    MyInput mi;
    ProcessA pa;

    pa.proc(mi); // Pass a MyInput

    return 0;
}
```

The output is (as expected):

> MyInput::display()

---

**EDIT** (answer to question's edit 1):

You have two solutions.

Either you defines in `BaseInput` the required methods to be implemented by every input type (as I did with `display()`). In your case, it could be a `getData()` member for example.

Or you will have to `dynamic_cast` your given `BaseInput &` into a `MyInput &`.
Keep in mind that if `dynamic_cast` fails with pointers, it returns a `nullptr`, but if it fails with references, it will throw a `std::bad_cast` exception.
As you use references, you will have to catch the exception in case of potential fail (if another type of input is given).

Comment: I extremely appreciate your answer. But there might be some misunderstanding. I've edited the question.

Comment: @StephanXu You're welcome. I've made an edit to answer yours.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll try.